# validate the formatString - of Type.ToString(formatString), Is there a builtin provision for this in C#?

Tags: c#

for example

DateTime dateTime= System.DateTime.Now;

//Get the formatString from user , example formatString = "dddd - d - mmmm";

//validate the formatStrong provided by the user.

if the format string is valid

string result = dateTime.ToString(formatString);

i know that one way would be to catch the expection while formatting.but i want to know if there is any class/method provided by .Net for this purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: What should count as a 'valid' format string?

Comment: anything which does not throw expection while formatting.

Comment: Looking at the code for DateTime.ToString(string) in Reflector shows that it calls a `private` method that manually checks the format string character-by-character and throws the exception. It looks pretty complicated.

Comment: Would be good ,if you can tell ,something similar exists for other datatypes as well like for Int.ToStrin(formatString), double.ToString(formatString).

Comment: I'm sorry, they use "extern" methods and I can't tell. If a public method existed like your asking for, I would think ToString would also call it. Since it doesn't, I'm guessing nothing exists.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry Nar, really misread your initial posting.  I am not aware of anything within DateTime to do this but an extension method might help.  This extension method encapsulates the try/catch block so you don't have to check it all the time.  Now you can check the format with a simple if statement.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string format = "#";

        DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now;

        if (myDate.ValidateFormat(format))
            Console.WriteLine(myDate.ToString(format));
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Bad format");

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    static bool ValidateFormat(this object obj, string format)
    {
        try
        {
            MethodInfo info = obj.GetType().GetMethod("ToString", new Type[] { format.GetType() });
            if (info == null)
                return false;
            info.Invoke(obj, new object[] { format });
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This ValidateFormat will work for any data type.  The only downside is that the extension is on object which means everything will have this method.  Those that don't have a ToString(format) meethod report back a false for invalid format.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that "I am not aware of anything within DateTime to do this but an extension method might help. " 
is what i want to make sure.

Comment: Why not just make this an extension method of the DateTime type?

Comment: This approach is dependent on the exception while formatting , but i want to validate(or know if it possible) without actually doing the formatting.

Comment: I know that it's a good idea to avoid causing exceptions, but in this case I think it's necessary. Unless it's causing a noticeable performance problem, I'd just catch the exception.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Turns out there is...[DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx)

Comment: TryParseExact is used if you are forcing matching to a particular format.  TryParse is probably what you are looking for in this example.

Comment: Yes but if the date cannot be converted to the specified format it will return false.

Comment: And that is when you return a message to the user that the format they entered is invalid.

Comment: Sorry, misread the posters intent.  TryParseExact is probably what you want.

Comment: Isn't this the opposite of what the question asked for? Starting with a DateTime object, Nar wants to convert it to a string with a formatString. This parses from a string to a DateTime.

Comment: yes,Greg is right. i am looking for Starting with a DateTime object, Nar wants to convert it to a string with a formatString.

Comment: I still think using the TryParseExact would do the trick, you would just call .ToString on the output date to conver to a string. You are also assured that it is a valid date.

Comment: if i have the output date that means, i have done the successfull formatting, in which case i wont need to check again.

TryParseExact checks whether the input dateTime string is in a specified format or not. But i want to check the specified format is a valid format or not.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand what it is you are trying to achieve then? Surely you are going to have to re-validate the date against the supplied format?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your scenario correctly, you are designing an application where the user can provide a date format for data conversion. You want to ensure that the date format itself is a valid .NET date format string.

If that's the case, what you want to do is test that format string against a known date value using DateTime.TryParseExact, just as others have described:

```
using System.Globalization; // For CultureInfo & DateTimeStyles    
class MyClass
{
    private bool IsValidDateFormatString(string userSuppliedFormat)
    {
        CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        DateTime testDate = new DateTime(2009, 10, 1, 12, 0, 0); // Noon on Oct 1st 2009
        bool result;

        result = DateTime.TryParseExact(userSuppliedFormat, enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, testDate);

        return result;

    }    
}
```

This should get you what you want. If necessary, add it as an extension method:

```
using System.Globalization;
public static class MyClass
{
    private bool IsValidDateFormat(this Date value)
    {
        CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        DateTime testDate = new DateTime(2009, 10, 1, 12, 0, 0); // Noon on Oct 1st 2009
        bool result;

        result = DateTime.TryParseExact(value, enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, testDate);
        return result;        
    }    
}
```

I'm not sure I'd go that far, however, since it seems like something you'd do *very* rarely.

Comment: My sentiments exactly, the format string HAS to be tested hence why I suggested using the TryParseExact method. However, looking at your code you could remove the local variable result and just return the result of the TryParseExact method directly :)

Comment: Using a result variable is a quirk of mine; I find them useful when I'm stepping through code in the debugger, and want to set a breakpoint to view the result before exiting the function. The cost of the additional variable is negligible, but the ability to view it while debugging is priceless.

Comment: That is not a valid overload of TryParseExact. The first parameter has to be a string containing a date and time to convert and the last parameter is an out parameter for the output of the parsing.

Comment: I don't believe this actually works... The problem is that the first parameter (as @Greg pointed out) must be a valid date in string format.  And it must match the format passed, because all `TryParseExact` does is to validate that the string date you have matches a format.  

In other words, you'd have to call `testDate.ToString(formatToTest)` before testing against `formatToTest`.  Which kind of defeats the purpose :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to do this is to validate a known-valid date and catch the FormatException.  Similar to what Mike Hofer stated, but a call to `TryParseExact` won't work (see my comments on his answer for why).

```
try {
    DateTime validDateTime = new DateTime(1904, 01, 31, 12, 59, 59);
    string discarded = validDateTime.ToString(FormatString);

    return true;
}
catch (FormatException) {
    return false;
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException) {
    return false;   //  But really, the developer is an idiot
}
```